# Problem while Installing Gnome using Terminal?

Tags: gnome

I was trying to install Gnome 3.10 in my Ubuntu 13.10..

I Entered the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next && sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next && sudo apt-get update
```

after some time when installation reached 60% it showed:

```
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

when I type apt-get update, it displays:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

and
    fix-missing: command not found

what to do?

Comment: ...maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing ???

Comment: not working, that's why I asked

Comment: You should specify in your question everything what you tried.

Comment: Do you currently have a version of Gnome installed?

Comment: what was the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for pmat: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` command not `apt-get update`.

Comment: follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html) to install gnome 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

More info [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10)